# svn how to get the content of another branch without having to deal with conflicts

Tags: svn

So I have this scenario, the main repo is called 'trunk', periodically i fork of that tree, and work on the branch for a while. say the branch is called mybranch.

But afterwards, all I need is to get the full dump of trunk, and refresh what's in 'mybranch'. there is no merge/resolve content needed since i really only want to get the latest of 'trunk'.

However when i try to do that the result is not what i expected. i get bunch of 'C' and other things, even worse, I can find files that's supposed to be updated but not.

So the question is, how can i just tell svn to take what's in 'trunk' and use that to replace what's in 'mybranch'?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `mybranch` :

```
svn delete repo/project/branches/mybranch -m "Deleting branch"
```

and create `mybranch` again from trunk:

```
svn cp repo/project/trunk repo/project/branches/mybranch -m "Refreshing mybranch from trunk"
```